# How to limit the amount of character in a textbox in vb 6.0

Tags: vb6, textbox

I am doing a registration system by using vb 6.0. I want for user to enter the mobile number. So I want the mobile number to be limited to 8 digits only. If the number is over 8 digits, when the user click save button, a message box will pop out to ask user to recheck the data again and it will not be save until the data is inserted correctly. What is the coding for me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let your user enter more characters than allowed, then tell them later they can't do that. The TextBox control has a property you can access from the designer named **MaxLength**. Set that property to 8 to limit the use to a maximum of 8 characters. Better still would be to use the MaskedEditBox and use the **Mask** property to enter a mask that limits and formats the user input. To add a MaskEditBox you need to open the Components window and add the **Microsoft Masked Edit Control 6.0** to your toolbox. You can then add the control to your form.

Comment: Thanks both of the replied. I never notice that MaxLength thing. How silly I am to asking such silly question. LOL! Thank a lot